# Silverlight Navigation Application

Tags: silverlight

Is there anyway I can have one mainpage, with tabs, which load child pages in the content area, but also have within the child page another navigation menu which loads siblings into the same content area it itself is in?

This is just a nested navigation frame situation really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a second navigation frame. Simply set the datacontext of the hyperlink button on the nested page to the page where your navigation frame is, that way it can be targeted.